# Significance of the DEGREE of Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, intuition

Can anybody gives the idea why degree of a differential equation is important?. Every differential equation book writes the definition of "degree of a differential equation". But, why do we care about this definition? What we will get just by remembering definition of degree of a differential equation ?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians love to classify things. The degree is one criterium to classify differential equations. Another one is for instance linear/non-linear.

Different methods of solution are appropriate for equations of different degree. And you have general results like: the general solution of an differential equation of degree $n$ depends on $n$ constants.

Comment: linear/non-linear some extant ok but it doesn't completely classify linear/non-linear things. Second statement you made that is related to only ORDER of a differential equation not for DEGREE.

Comment: I misunderstood. I have checked several "classical" books on differential equations (but certainly not all.) The only ones I found that mention the degree are from 1888 and 1931. I have been teaching differential equation several years, and never mentioned it in my lectures.

Comment: Word "every" I used here as sentimental, but several book I have seen they are defined the degree of a differential equation and I couldn't find anything worthfull.